recusion formula for $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$
$X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$
show that the moments of $X$ follow the follwing recusion formula
$\mathbb{E}\left[ X^{n+1} \right]=n\mathbb{E}\left[ X^{n-1} \right] , n\ge 2$
the first induction step is quite easy to see. by expanding $\mathbb{E}\left[ \left( X-\mu \right)^3 \right]$ we get
$\mathbb{E}\left[ X^3 \right] =\mathbb{E}\left[ \left( X-\mu \right)^3 \right]=0=n \mathbb{E}\left[ X \right]$
But I couldn't really get any further with the next induction step. Would be grateful for help :)

Integrating by parts we get
\begin{align}
\sqrt {2\pi}\mathbb{E}X^{n+1}&=\int x^{n+1}e^{-x^{2}/2}dx
\\ &
=-x^{n}e^{-x^{2}/2}|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+n\int x^{n-1}e^{-x^{2}/2}dx
\\&
=0+\sqrt {2\pi} n\mathbb{E}X^{n-1}.
\end{align}
